# Jquery "$("*:focus")" is empty. How to detect where is the focus?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im working with jQuery. There are input fields with ID's and attached .blur() events. The problem comes when I try to figure out the very new item where the focus is on:

```
$("#"+field).blur(function()
{
 console.log ($(this).attr('id')+' -> '+$("*:focus").attr('id'));
}
```

but this **$("*:focus").attr('id')** is undefined. How to detect where is the focus?

Comment: Try `$(":focus").attr('id')`, `$(':focus')` will select all focus element. You don't need `*`

Comment: what if you simply try to print `console.log($(":focus"))` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that on a large DOM a selector like this will be very slow, so try not to do it too often.

Comment: ok this: console.log ($(this).attr('id')+' -> '+$(":focus").attr('id')); is still undefined

Comment: Are you adding the new input dinamically?

Comment: no, they are in fix HTML code - if you meant that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem the blur/focus events are fired before a new element actually gets the `:focus` pseudo-class attached to it. Which is pretty interesting. Proof of what I mean in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MevpE/14/)

So that begs the question - why are you trying to do this? :)

My **solution** to your problem (if you absolutely need it like that) is to do it like so : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MevpE/19/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that you try to get the item which has got focus but you do it to early. So what you do is this:

```
blur event gets fired
you try to get the element which has got focus
new element gets focus
```

Sure the easiest thing would be to add event listener for focus but if you don't want to do that this would be the trick:

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($(":focus"));
    }, 1);
});​​
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hajbd/)**

### UPDATE

So actually the best solution would be the following because if you set a timeout it always depends on perfomance:

```
var sTempId;
$("input")
    .focus(function() {
        if (sTempId)
            console.log ( sTempId + " -> " + $(this).attr("id") );
        sTempId = $(this).attr("id");
    });​
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hajbd/3)**

Comment: That will make `$(this).attr('id')` return undefined though.

Comment: If you use your technique with the code he actually wants to use, you will get "undefined -> focusedid" instead of "lastfocusid -> undefined".

Comment: no he can still save the id in a temp var before and use it after instead.

Comment: yea, I was thinking this way... I try to get the focused item at the very wrong tine